# How can I color/highlight a candle that closed above 5EMA and did not touch it

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking for help on code where the candles are highlighted when they meet following conditions:

1. It closed above 5 EMA
2. It's high or low didn't touch 5 EMA at all

Here's partial code from another thread but it does not address the 'close above 5EMA' condition

```
EMA5 = ta.ema(close, 5)
bgcolor(low > EMA5 or high < EMA5 ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just add `(close > EMA5)` to your condition. You can also use the `barcolor()` function to change the candlestick bar's color.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
EMA5 = ta.ema(close, 5)
plot(EMA5)
bgcolor((close > EMA5) and (low > EMA5 or high < EMA5) ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na)
barcolor((close > EMA5) and (low > EMA5 or high < EMA5) ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. A follow-up question if I may: I want a shape to be plotted on the next candle if it meets the below conditions (both).

Condition 1: Previous candle's open close high and low were above EMA5
Condition 2: Active candle is breaking previous candle's low 

Excuse if it's a stupid question, I never coded in my life.

Comment: Please ask a new question for that and I will answer there.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vitruvius - just posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875267/need-help-in-coding-following-conditions